# Restrict SOAP calls using Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: soap, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have a Nginx server configured for reverse proxying to protect an aging SOAP server that can't be patched.

I've been asked to restrict what calls clients can make from specific IP ranges.

I've no idea how to allow some SOAP calls but filter out others.

The Nginux config is

```
server  {
  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443;
  server_name shiny.nginx.server;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate "/public/directory/proxy.pem";
  ssl_certificate_key "/secret/directory/proxy.key";
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://very.old.server:80/;
    proxy_buffering                     off;
    proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    auth_basic                          "Username and Password Required";
    auth_basic_user_file                /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
}
```

Any ideas how I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to google before asking. https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/redirect-nginx-traffic-client-ip/

Comment: Thanks but the redirection is working.  The problem is all SOAP calls/requests are allowed.  We want to restrict what calls some users can make.

Comment: The idea is for you to check the IP, then check the url, then redirect, else return 404. This way you can specific specific IP to use specific URL only.

Comment: OK, but the URL doesn't contain the SOAP call.  Looking at the access.log file, all I see is '192.168.1.67 - user [07/Mar/2019:11:16:06 +0800] "POST /vendor/SOAP/ HTTP/1.1" 200 285 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)" "-"'.  Using wireshark, I can see the SOAP call embedded in the XML its not on the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v found a solution to this.

```
server  {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name shiny.nginx.server;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate "/public/directory/proxy.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/secret/directory/proxy.key";
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://very.old.server:80/;
    proxy_buffering                     off;
    proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    auth_basic                          "Username and Password Required";
    auth_basic_user_file                /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    if ($remote_addr ~ 192.168.1.1) {
        set $is_user Y;
    }
    if ($http_soapaction ~ SOAP/Request/Goes/Here) {
        set $user_allowed Y;
    }
    set $user_test "${is_user}${user_allowed}";
    if ($user_test = YY) {
        set $good yes;
    }

    if ($good != yes) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Not being able to do nested or complex tests made it a bit tricky...